# Use cases for Login Flows

Tags: administration, flow, login

As an administrator, I am curious to know how I can improve or enhance the user experience. To this end I would like to know if there are any use cases in particular that the apply to the new Login Flows feature (WI15).

Comment: If you're going to be at Dreamforce, you should attend [Customizing User Authentication with Login Flows](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions#/session/a2q30000000hvTA). If not, watch for the recording on YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could use it for example to gather further information from the user to decide what Data categories you want to give them access too if logging in via communities, or you have a different way to authenticate the user via some other authentication process.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, [http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_login_flows.htm]

This feature basically allows us to integrate a Login Step, in the usual Flow scenarios. So, if there is a business process that you have in mind, which you think can be built using Salesforce Flow, then with this new feature, you can integrate a Login Step as a part of this business process.

Another way to look at this is, this allows you to reduce the number of steps required in executing a flow. Without this features, if you have a business process which was executed on an 'Event' such as a click of a button on a standard / visual force page, now you no longer need to attach a specific event for the flow to start. A Flow can be triggered as soon as a user is logged in into a system.

Flow's in generation are best suited for implementing 'Short Running' business processes, such as

- Fill a questionnaire
- Capture Complex Data in a Step by Step process. etc.

I very simple scenario could be, in a call centre operation, if a user uses multiple systems to complete a task, then based on various factors, such as Type of activity being logged', a different set of fields can be displayed on the same flow screens.

You can also augment this scenario with other factors such as Time & IP Address. 
(e.g. certain data is only visible when the user logs in from a pre-determined IP Address at a pre-determined time)

Comment: Thanks for these ideas.  More precisely, could you have a process apply for prospects (unauthenticated, working as Guest user) and a subprocess for customers (authenticated) ?

Answer (score 2):

I've just had a look at these and these were the scenarios we came up with:

1. Adding your own second factor authentication (the release notes use this as an example)
2. Announcements where you need, or want, the user to acknowledge that they have read them. For example release notes or new changes.